# Critiquing my function to skip k chars from input stream

Tags: c

Working on (what should be) a simple project, taking the input from stdin and reformatting it to match the output specs. I'm just wanting to see what the experts here think of the following function that is supposed to skip k chars up to the end of the line, unless k < 0, where it will keep skipping chars until it reaches newline.

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
 25 int skip(int count){
 26   int i;
 27   int ch;
 28
 29   for(i = 0; count < 0 || i < count; i++){
 30     ch = fgetc(stdin);
 31     if(ch == EOF){
 32       return -1;
 33     }
 34     if(ch == '\n'){
 35       return 0;
 36     }
 37   }
 38   return 1;
 39 }
```

(including the line numbers for reference purposes)

Comment: You don't mean "spaces" do you? It looks like it is skipping chars

Comment: Your code doesn't behave as you describe.  If it encounters a newline it will skip less than k characters if k >= 0.

Comment: @Dan: You are correct, however, that was my intention. Let me rephrase the function spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing seriously wrong with this code.  But to make this more robust, I would:

1. Save the value of `fgetc(stdin)` to an `int` variable, then test it to make sure it's a blank using `isspace()`, reporting an error if not.  Use an `int` not a `char` because `fgetc()` returns `EOF` at end of file, which cannot fit inside a `char`.
2. Another minor concern is that on modern filesystems, file sizes can be larger than `INT_MAX`.  Instead of "faking" a `count` value of `INT_MAX` when `k` < 0, I would change the loop test to test it explicitly.

In summary, the main loop becomes:

```
int ch;
for (i = 0; k < 0 || i < k; ++i) {
    ch = fgetc(stdin);
    if (ch == '\n') {
        return 1;
    } else if (ch == EOF) {
        return -1;        /* Or some error code of your choice */
    } else if (!isspace(ch)) {
        return -2;        /* Or some error code of your choice */
    }
}
```

Comment: well, I was ambiguous about the usage of the word 'space'. I should have said 'column', as there is mostly garbage data for the first k columns of each line. But thanks for the tip on INT_MAX. Since I'm only working on one line of input, its moot, but I like to write more robust than I need to.

Comment: No problem.  Actually testing for EOF correctly is probably more important than the INT_MAX business, but as you say it never hurts to be more robust than necessary :)

Answer (score 0):

Not bad. If you worked with me and you wrote that code, I wouldn't ask you to change it.

You could decrement `count` until it reaches zero, instead of incrementing `i` until it reaches `count`, but it's arguable whether that would be an improvement or not.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer

```
if (k < 0) count = 0
else       count = k;

do {
  if(fgetc(stdin) == '\n') return 1;
  count--;
} while (count != 0);

return 0;
```

to avoid INT_MAX usage. Note that the first two lines also simply could be changed to "count = k;" and that you could change the count variable to a 64-bit type for handling inputs > 2 GB.

If you're having large inputs, you could also try to read whole lines or even the whole file into a buffer and passing a pointer to the skip function to increase performance.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I wouldn't use the comparison with `INT_MAX` and the separate count variable, and I'd decrement the supplied value rather than use a `for` loop.

I might even do:

```
while (k < 0 || k--) {
    ...
}
```

Note that if `(k < 0)` the decrement never happens due to the `||` operator's short-circuit behaviour, so you get an infinite loop unless you break out of the loop per your example for `\n`

if `(k == 0)` the loop will terminate immediately (nb: post-decrement rather than pre-decrement)

Answer (score 0):

critic: you formatting:

") {" with a space between is more readable

sometimes you use "if(expression) statement;" and sometimes "if(expression){statement;}". i would always use the "{".

"while (", "if (" on also with a space after the keyword.

Comment: I'll agree with you on always using the {} after an if, while, etc. I'm trying to retrain myself out of a bad habit of not using them on single statement clauses. However, I will have to respectfully disagree with the "){" vs ") {". I already have a hard time keeping line length < 80 chars.

Comment: keep to the standard (in this case K&R "programming in C")